# Compute: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} − A_n)$ where $A_n = \frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}, {n\geq 1}$, be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $|a_n|\leq 1$ for all $n$. Define  $$A_n =
\frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n),$$ for $n\geq 1$. Then find $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} − A_n)$ .

I proceed in this way 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} − A_n)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}\left[\frac{1}{n+1}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n+a_{n+1})-\frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n})\right]=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[{(na_{n+1}-a_1 - a_2 - \cdots - a_n})\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}\right]$$  Please help me to complete from here

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya Did you want to create a tag called ([tag:stolz-cesaro]) rather than ([tag:stolz-cesare]). (A separate question is whether or not the new tag is going to be useful. I left also a few comments [in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2020/1/25) - maybe somebody will left some feedback there about what they think of this new tag.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, yes, it should be Cesaro. I hope I didn't break the rules, if so I apologise. I thought my colleagues would find interesting answers regarding the material we are dealing with at the moment. I noticed they keep asking me the same questions, many of which can be easily found here, but it doesn't seem so. Anyway I apologise for not telling the staff before.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya I am not really sure what you mean by "telling the staff". Anyway, as you probably know, some people prefer new tags to be discussed on meta first, you might find some discussion about this here: [Should every new tag be discussed on meta before creation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17023) A good place where to suggest new tags might be [tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020). (Or a separate question, if the issue is likely to generate longer discussion.)

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest to [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2020/1/26), so that we do not leave here many comments unrelated to the actual question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You almost solved the problem with your calculation. Now you just have to note that with $|a_n|\le1$ we have $$|na_{n+1}-a_1-\cdots-a_n|\le2n\;,$$ so $$\left|\frac{na_{n+1}-a_1-\cdots-a_n}{\sqrt n(n+1)}\right|\le\frac{2n}{\sqrt n(n+1)}\to0\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Notice that
\begin{align*}|\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1}-A_n)-0|&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n+1)}|na_{n+1}-a_1-a_2-\cdots-a_n|\\&\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n+1)}(n|a_n|+|a_1|+|a_2|+\cdots|a_n|)\\ &\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n+1)}(n+1+1+\cdots+1)\\&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n+1)}(n+n)\\&=\frac{2\sqrt{n}} {n+1}.\end{align*}
Since $\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}} {n+1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N_+}$ such that $$|\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1}-A_n)-0| \leq \dfrac{2\sqrt{n}} {n+1}<\varepsilon$$when $n>N.$ According to the $\varepsilon-N$ definition of the limit, we can conclude that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1}-A_n)=0.$$

Comment: Although your Answer is longer than the 5+ year old Accepted Answer, it is almost entirely a repetition of material already expanded in the Question together with the essential approach of the Accepted Answer.