# find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} − A_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$, be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $|a_n|\leq 1$ for all
$n$.

let $A_n =
\frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)$, for $n\geq 1$. Then find 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} − A_n)$$.

My attempt:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} − A_n)$

=$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}[$$\frac{1}{n+1}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n+a_{n+1})-$$\frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n}$)]

=$\lim \frac{na_{n+1}-a_n}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)} $

I need suggestion here. thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172305/find-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtna-n1-%E2%88%92-a-n-where-a-n-frac1?rq=1

Comment: I think  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} − A_n)$

=$\lim \frac{na_{n+1}-A_n}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)} $

Comment: @math110 howz numertor less than 2n in that answerp

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1}-A_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}(n/(n+1)A_n+a_{n+1}/(n+1)-A_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\dfrac{a_{n+1}-A_n}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{na_{n+1}-a_1-\cdots-a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}:=l$$ Thus $|l|\le \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}=0$ since $|a_n|\le 1\forall n$

Comment: Howz numerator less than 2n

Comment: Using the fact that $|a_n|\le 1$ and the triangle inequality.